# What are those glassfish threads doing?

Tags: java, glassfish, jvm

Since yesterday, our glassfish backend server has stopped responding 3 times (exposing remote ejb's, thus communicating via rmi-iiop).

Restarting the front servers didn't change the situation, restarting the back servers did. So, we are pretty sure the problem is on the back.

We took thread dumps, but looking at it doesn't bring anything obvious to us. Comparing it with thread dumps of the same server after restart (working) didn't neither.

Here is the thread dump: http://pastebin.com/ykjgD1m6

Comment: What gf version are you running?

Comment: Have you hooked up Visual VM to see what it's doing? Is the cpu maxed, what about memory, etc...?

Comment: It's a complex setup where I can't do that. However, the traces I took give about the same information: jstack, pstack, ps, graphs from glassfish monitoring data... CPU is about 0%, memory usage is low, no unusual GC activity

Comment: The thread dump looks like everything is waiting for a request to come in (at least that's how it looks to me). I'd crank up the logging and look for something.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. Had the same (or so we thought) problem yesterday. Restarting the front did not help. Telling another front server to use this one as back did work. Then the first front responded again. Without restarting the back. Weird. Waiting for it to happen again...